# trying to restore iPhone from icloud backup

Tags: iphone, icloud, restore

I am trying to restore iPhone from iCloud backup that is shown in my iCloud account so I can get some notes that I lost.  There is the iPhone back up on iCloud that I want and an iPhone back up on my computer (that I don't want).  I am not being given options to back up from the icloud backup.  I am connected to wifi (both iPhone and computer). I am following the apple instructions.  I thoroughly searched for an answer on the web at large, the apple and iCloud websites and here and only find the "how to's" for how it should work normally, but that is not working.

Thank you for any advice

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense as it's written.  Please read [ask] and edit your question to contain the relevant info.  Also, make sure you're following the [Apple instructions](https://support.apple.com/kb/ph12521?locale=en_US) for restoring your iCloud backup and post any errors you're receiving.

Comment: Sorry.  My "notes" were inadvertently deleted by a well meaning friend.  I am trying to back up my iPhone to an old iCloud back up that is shown in my iCloud account related to my iPhone.  However when I try to "restore from backup," it only gives me the option of the backup that is on my computer, not the iCloud version that I want to use.

Comment: Are they accessible in the Recently Deleted section of Notes?

Comment: I do not seem to have a "recently deleted" section

Comment: Check out [this article](http://osxdaily.com/2016/05/10/recover-deleted-notes-ios/) and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Notes aren't tied to iPhone backups in any way, they're tied to iCloud directly. If you can't find them in "recently deleted" (within notes) there is nothing you can do. Restoring the iCloud backup will have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

All of first you have to visit https://www.icloud.com then sign in with your right **Apple ID** and browse the source you stow their.